# jQuery in Fancybox not working html() and hide()

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I currently have Fancybox open a hidden_div afterShow()

There is a link on hidden_div that calls this function:

```
        $('#image_tagged').html('');       // these work
        $('#image_name_tagged').hide();    // these work
        $('#image_tagged_fancybox').live("remove icons", function(){  // this does not work
            $(this).html('');
        });
        $('#image_tagged_fancybox_name').hide();  // this does not work
    }
});
```

The jQuery with `#image_tagged` and `#image_name_tagged work` -- these IDs are not on top of the fancybox-overlay (the hidden tab after fancybox is called).

The jQuery with `#image_tagged_fancybox` (the jQuery called from links within the hidden tab) do not work. Interestingly...

```
$('#image_tagged_fancybox_name').html();
```

still gives me the correct information.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: 1. I would suggest you using `on` rather than `live`. 2. `remove icons` is it a custom event ?

Comment: I have never seen the `remove icons` event either.

Comment: Even if I simply used $('#image_tagged_fancybox').html(''); it will not work

Comment: If you pretend to write an white space with `$('#image_tagged_fancybox').html('');` then use `$('#image_tagged_fancybox').empty();` instead